# Javascript setting uniqueId() as array keys

Tags: javascript, json

Should be a simple answer, could be that my syntax is not correct since I am new to ReactJS.  I would like to assign a unique id as the key.

This throws an error:

```
rows:{
  uniqueId() : { name:"Kitchen Remodel", value:20100 },
  uniqueId() : { name:"Basement Remodel", value:8300 }
}
```

This does not? Please explain...

```
rows:{
  143434 : { name:"Kitchen Remodel", value:20100 },
  984578 : { name:"Basement Remodel", value:8300 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: _the array of objects in an object_? You can make your example work in new and modern JS by using `[uniqueId()]` so that the name of the key is evaluated, but I don't really understand what your goal is.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be anything specific to ReactJS, and it seems to already have some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: Candy thanks, that question seems to be on point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer), you can use a function call or variable for the property name like so:

```
rows:{
  [uniqueId()] : { name:"Kitchen Remodel", value:20100 },
  [uniqueId()] : { name:"Basement Remodel", value:8300 }
}
```

Comment: I thought there was some syntax issue.  I am using ES6 this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side cannot be evaluated, when you are declaring an object like this.

You might want to do declare/assign like below

```
var row = {}; 
row[unique_id()] = { name:"Kitchen Remodel", value:20100 };
row[unique_id()] = { name:"Basement Remodel", value:8300 };
```

Comment: I see.  I did not know it could not be something evaluated, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is more a JS (language) phenomenon than React (library). You might want to edit/update your question.

Comment: I was not sure if it was an issue with the uniqueId() function.